# Creating C++ Library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, header-files

Can I include and make use of header files if I have C++ header and C++ Source?
How can I do so in VB 2008?

eg. I have genlib c++ header and genlib c++ source.
I want to use all functions in source to be accessible in my program when I type #include genlib.h

How can I do it when such headers and source are in bulk and may depend on each other.
eg. [StanfordCs106BHeaderandSOurce](https://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib)

And Is there any solution so that I dont have to add any addition dependencies whenever I create a project,just like .
May be copping and pasting in program file